# How to get full info from given site url in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get full info by given site url.

For example:

```
$href = 'http://example.com/news/news-1';
```

I can get post id by

```
$post_id = url_to_postid( $href );
```

Then I can get post type by

```
$post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
```

But it gives me nothing if it's a category url. So is there any other way to get info on given site url? Is this page even exist? Is it a page or a post? Is it a category?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [get_queried_object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) it will returns the queried objevt type, id etc.

Here is an example:

`$current_item = get_queried_object();`

Comment: I don't understand how this will help me. It would do the trick if I was already on a page that I want to get info from. But I only have an ulr string. Passing url to get_queried_object() won't work.

Comment: `url_to_postid()` works only if you pass post or page id. For category id you should white your own function.
Can you please provide more details where do you use this code? Is there any reason why don't you use the conditional logic functions or global `wp_query`?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of `is_` functions help you to determine type of node (`is_single`, `is_category` etc - check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/page/31/ and next pages). Then you get all info about this node.

Comment: All I have is url string. Passing it to a, for example, `is_404()` function won't work.

Comment: You should extract `post_id` before checking.

Comment: if I use `url_to_postid()` for a category url like this - `http://example.com/news` I will recieve `post_id` = 0. I guess I need to get slug from url string and then start checking by `is_` functions..